# How do I replace a drain stack?

Tags: plumbing

So I had just had a shower upstairs this past weekend and went downstairs to do the laundry and I discovered that the floor near the pipes was wet. See photo

[image: Pipe]

I immediately went and bought some GOOP and sealed the cracked section of pipe and then I called a plumber to fix it and he said he would be able to handle it sometime this week. Well I never heard back from him (we've had crazy terrible weather) and now I'm thinking that maybe I could just do the work myself.

How do I replace a drain stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can replace the split part. It requires a stack jack.  This is not real easy for a DIYer.  the procedure is to grasp the stack, cut out the bad part, jack the stack, put in couplings and replace the bad section.  You then have to check the boots or replace them.  this may be a job for a pro with the right tools.  sorry.......   good luck

Comment: Thanks for the advice shirlock, looks like I should just call a new plumber.